# Getting direction vector of Project Tango's rgb camera

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I'm creating an augmented reality app for project tango and I need to render a simple 3D model on top of the rgb camera input shown on the tablet screen.

In order to do this I need the *direction* the camera is pointing to, relative to a known component (e. g. the tablet screen). It's not just a right angle direction as one might assume.

Because we are not using tango's built-in position data (but an external positioning system) the existing AR examples are not very useful for our case.

There are documented ways of reading out the camera position and rotation, but unfortunately the api seems not to be working properly: It says one can get the pose between e. g. the screen and the rgb camera (see https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/intrinsics-extrinsics, right down at the bottom of the page). But for some components of the tablet I get a TangoException. The same api works fine to get the pose between the IMU and the rgb camera, but it's not working for e. g. the screen and the rgb camera.

Some components just don't work and those are the components that could solve my problem.

Now I'm stuck because I don't know which direction the rendering camera for the 3D-Model should have. I tried to approximate the vector, but the result is not very precise.

Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What environment are you using, what language did you program in so far?

Comment: I'm using Unity3d/C# for the AR project. In addition to that I use Java/AndroidSDK to access the Tango APIs.

Comment: _"In order to do this I need the direction the camera is pointing to, relative to a known component (e. g. the tablet screen)"_ What do you mean by this? The camera **is** the tablet screen, I don't understand.

Comment: The tablet screen is flat and thereby a good reference point. When the tango api tells me the camera is rotated like x degrees away from the screen I can rotate the 3d camera in unity x degrees (expressed by a direction vector) and I'm done. However, if I don't know how the reference component is rotated (e. g. camera 2) or even where it is located (e. g. the IMU component) I cannot go to unity and adjust the rotation of the camera that renders my 3d model. I should add: I'm talking about the rgb camera on the back side of the tablet.

Comment: Well you say _camera is rotated like x degrees away from the screen_ but in fact in my `Unity`, the `Camera` is my screen. So in my app there is a **Tango Prefab** `GameObject` that has as a child component a `Camera` and when I rotate the phone, the `Camera` rotates as well.

Comment: You must be using the official tango plugin for Unity. I'm planning to use it as well now - it seems to solve all those questions. Last time I tried it out it crashed in my environment and I didn't have time to figure out what the reason was. The current plugin however seems to work fine and I'll give it an other shot. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No worries, keep in mind some people have issues with the `AR Camera` with the latest **Ganiko** release, I advise using **Eisa** if you are having issues. Good luck!